# Can this 2 dimensional array work?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

so far ive got:

```
var Items = new Array(5); // this array contains the items
BodyPaint = new Array(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);  // this array gives stats for the item
WolfFur = new Array(3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);       // ^^
BearFur = new Array(4, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);       // ^^
WolfSkin = new Array(6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);     // ^^
BearSkin = new Array(7, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);     // ^^
```

would this array work? im relatively new to programing and my friend suggested this is how i should do it, but i looked around and everywhere else recommends a more complex way of doing it that might make sense were they to explain it.
if this array would work please tell me how i would access values in the second array
so far to access the 1st stat for wolf fur ive got this:

```
var example = Items.2.1
```

would this (^^) work?

and if it wouldnt work, please tell me how to do it using the above names in the example and explaining why you do everything you do and what it does.
thx.

Im now using an object, ive got:

```
var Items = {
    BodyPaint : new Array(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    FurCloak : new Array(3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    WolfSkin : new Array(5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)};
```

there are more arrays but i ended it here to save space
i get the following errors:
Unknown identifier: BodyPaint
Unknown identifier: FurCloak
Unknown identifier: WolfSkin
and for all of my other arrays
if i replace a name with a number the error goes but it cant be good for the code and i dont really want my items to be refered to as numbers here, i wont b able 2 know which is which

Answer (score 2):

No. It's that's not how you get values from an array.

`Items[2][1]` would work if your array were something like this;

```
var BodyPaint = new Array(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);  // this array gives stats for the item
var WolfFur   = new Array(3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);       // ^^
var BearFur   = new Array(4, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);       // ^^
var WolfSkin  = new Array(6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);     // ^^
var BearSkin  = new Array(7, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);     // ^^
Items = [BodyPaint, WolfFur, BearFur, WolfSkin, BearSkin];
```

`Items[2][1]` would return 0.

---

**Edit**: You might be interested in using an object too.

```
var Items = {
     BodyPaint: new Array(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
     WolfFur:   new Array(3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
     BearFur:   new Array(4, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
     WolfSkin:  new Array(6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
     BearSkin:  new Array(7, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
}
```

This would allow you to write some code like this:

`Items.BearFur[1]` would return 0 and is the same as `Items[2][1]` above.

Comment: thx for objects example, i might use it, but atm my items are refered to as havind IDs so i think ill use an array, and why would Items[2][1] return 0? does the array start counting at zero? so BodyPaint would be 0? sorry for noob question

Comment: Yep. Arrays start at 0 in almost every programming language.

Comment: used an object but i get an error telling me to add a semicolon at the end after the }, when i do it gets loads of errors (Unknow identifier: "BodyPaint") for every single array, but wen i replace the name with a number the error for that array goes, is there a way to fix? is it ok to use numbers?

Comment: if you use @CoryDanielson's example and add a semicolon you should not get errors

Comment: @Christophe i am using cory's example and i hav added a semicolon, as ive edited the op to say, im getting unknown identifier errors about the names of the arrays (BodyPaint, WolfFur etc...)

Comment: @empire2202 maybe you could post your test on jsfiddle.net? This would make debugging easier.

Comment: Sounds like you've added semi-colons inbetween the arrays inside of the object. You need to use a common between them. Look at the 2 sets of code, you'll see commas where the semi-colons are in the array example

Answer (score 0):

You only have multiple 1D arrays, you should combine them into 2D, like :

```
var Items = new Array
BodyPaint = new Array(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
WolfFur = new Array(3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
BearFur = new Array(4, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
WolfSkin = new Array(6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
BearSkin = new Array(7, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);

Items[0] = BodyPaint;

alert(Items[0][2]);
```

In that case you have 2D, and with the alert example you can access the items

Answer (score 0):

It would not work because you aren't linking Items in any way to any of the other arrays. You would have to write:

```
var BodyPaint = new Array(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
var WolfFur = new Array(3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
var BearFur = new Array(4, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
var WolfSkin = new Array(6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
var BearSkin = new Array(7, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
var Items = new Array(BodyPaint, WolfFur, BearFur, WolfSkin, BearSkin);
```

Then this would work:

```
var example = Items[2][1];
```

I would recommend that you use a JavaScript Object instead of arrays. In JSON, this would be:

```
var Items = {
   BodyPaint : Array(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
   WolfFur : new Array(3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
   BearFur : new Array(4, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
   WolfSkin : new Array(6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
   BearSkin : new Array(7, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)};
```

You can then add new items like this:

```
Items.AnotherItem = new Array(8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Or:

```
Items['AnotherItem'] = new Array(8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

And get a property like:

```
var example = Items.WolfSkin[5];
```

JavaScript Objects are very flexible an I recommend you take some time to really get to know them.

Comment: ok, thx 4 all of your quick replies, im going to use this system to store all the items in my rpg and how they alter your stats. do you think using an object would suit me better? if so please direct me to an advances object tutorial. thx.

Comment: thx for ur help, ive used an object now like above but it wants me to put a semicolon after the second curly bracket }, and when i insert it it gives me loads of errors saying Unknown identifier: "BodyPaint", Unknown identifier: "WolfFur" etc for all of the arrays

Comment: My apologies. I seem to have made a few typos. I edited the answer to correct

Comment: it still doesnt like the names (bodypaint, wolffur etc..) it says unknow identifier

Comment: The names are case sensitive

Comment: i mean, i type the code and im using unity so it gives me errors wen things go rong, it says Unknown identifier: Bodypaint, Unknown identifier: WolfFur ... for all of them

Comment: so i havent even tried calling the stuff, i just type the code as above and unity gives me the error unknown identifier for all the names